# Google Cloud service stopped and never restarting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been using the Google Cloud speech recognition service for some time, through a python application.

Due to accidentally copying my Google Cloud json file to a GitHub shared location (I was doing a backup), I suddenly got a warning from Google Cloud that I was violating the rules as json is private. Then, I promptly removed the file, but nevertheless, I got an email saying that my resources for my project "santo1" were suspended, saying some reasons of "cryptocurrency mining" which I have no idea.

I applied to reactivate and my appeal was accepted promptly, saying that my resources about santo1 were reinstated.

Unfortunately, the speech recognition still didn't work.
Launching it from python, it records from the microphone but no answer from the service - and no error messages at all.

Then I attempted the following:

1. regenerate API
2. create a new json
3. create a new project with its own json under my same google account
4. as suggested by the Google Cloud chat operator, I manually clicked play to the VM resource that appeared stopped
5. create a new gmail account, with another new project, setup with billing and everything (also reconfigured through "gcloud init")

None of these attempts worked.
I need assistance on this, as the chat operator didn't seem capable of telling me more.

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to contact GCP support for this case as your cloud service could be still in suspended status regardless your access is OK

Apparently, the access key is stolen and used by hackers and they did crypto mining using your GCP account, hence your service account was banned

If it's your testing account/project, you should consider to create a new project rather than continue with it, the hacker could create some other services which you may not realize until too late 
Worse case is it's your PROD service, then you'd better review the bill and transaction report thoroughly